# Android Live Wallpaper crashes on Amazon App Store Testing ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, amazon-appstore

I am trying to put my live wallpaper on Amazon App Store(This live wallpaper is already live on Google Play Store), However, when I uploaded same APK for testing on Amazon Developer site it reports following exception

> 03-06 06:00:50.741  7598  7598 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-06 06:00:50.741  7598  7598 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rrapps.heavensdoor/com.rrapps.heavensdoor.PreviewActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle act=android.service.wallpaper.CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER (has extras)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5204)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>    Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle act=android.service.wallpaper.CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER (has extras)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1627)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
>       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
>       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
>       at com.rrapps.heavensdoor.PreviewActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5170)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2182)

following is code where I am setting wallpaper

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        /*
         * Open live wallpaper preview (API Level 16 or greater).
         */
        intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
        String pkg = MyWallpaperService.class.getPackage().getName();
        String cls = MyWallpaperService.class.getCanonicalName();
        intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
                new ComponentName(pkg, cls));
    } else {
        /*
         * Open live wallpaper picker (API Level 15 or lower).
         *
         * Display a quick little message (toast) with instructions.
         */
        intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
        Resources res = getResources();
        String hint = res.getString(R.string.picker_toast_prefix)
                + res.getString(R.string.lwp_name)
                + res.getString(R.string.picker_toast_suffix);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, hint, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I am not sure what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this will crash for sure because amazon fire os does not support live wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

Android is a funny world and implicit intents unfortunately, vary more than we (developers) would like them to. Specially for Amazon devices, that are not required to comply with Google test suite. On my app, I've seen `ActivityNotFoundException` trying to launch the web-browser.

So my suggestion, even tho it doesn't actually fix the issue, it's just try catch it:

```
try{
   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
   // why amazon, why?
}
```

Comment: "for testing on Amazon Developer site" is that an automated test or a manual test done by Amazon people?

Comment: I guess automated tests

Comment: I'm asking that because I wonder if it's an automated test, it's probably a simulated device that doesn't have all the stuff, so it fails. Ultimately, you only known for sure if it works or not is by getting a Fire tablet and testing on it, but if it's automated there's good chances that work fine on the real device.

Comment: okay ! but i dont hav access to a real device :( but thanks !